# Fetch all fields of an entity and their data, for a simple clone Rule

Tags: entities, rules

I don't think this is possible out of the box in Rules, but I would like to create a Rule that clones an entity of a specific type.

Using for example a Rules Link as trigger, the The bundle type of the entity is known.

However, the Rules Link must work for all BUDLES of one entity TYPE. So I can't hard-code the fields in a Rule of which the data value need to be set.

Validating the existence of all fields is not possible since there are too many fields available in the entity TYPE.

Is it possible to make Rules 'fetch' the list of fields that are attached to a BUNDLE?
In that way, I can create a loop that copy pasts the field values from the original entity.

Comment: Have you looked at Entity::createDuplicate,  It would be like `$clone = $entity->createDuplicate();`

Comment: @Dylan How would I use that in Rules?